# How do you initialize reference type class properties in a nullable context in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you are supposed to use the `Start()` or `Awake()` methods instead of the class constructors in Unity to initialize your class properties, VisualStudio complains that the reference types must have a non-null value when exiting the constructor if you are within a nullable context:

```
#nullable enable
using UnityEngine;

public class NullableTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Non-nullable field 'something' must contain a non-null value when exiting
    // constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable:
    private GameObject something;

    void Start()
    {
        something = new GameObject();
    }
}
```

You could set all your reference typed properties to nullable, but that would force you to check for null every time you dereference a property even after you initialized it in the `Start()` method.

Is there a correct way of handling this in Unity?

Comment: Not be in a nullable context ...? Or as the message tells you, declare te field nullable ..

Comment: @derHugo Yes, but I am asking because I want to be in a nullable context and take advantage of these warnings. If there is no nice way of doing this, the nullable contexts become very cumbersome to use in Unity, right?

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't make much sense for exactly the reason you mentioned: For `MonoBehaviour` we don't use the constructor but initializer methods ..

Comment: @derHugo This is why I was wondering if there is some clever way to take advantage of the nullable context in Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) "!". Just like this:

```cs
private GameObject something = null!;
```